# How do I fix 'MultipleObjectsReturned' error in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API using Django rest framework. I currently have an endpoint `/api/v1/device-groups/` which returns all device group objects like this:

```
 [
    {
        "device_group_name": "Default",
        "group_uuid": "3812a299-3ab9-4c00-a711-d166fb01075e",
        "color": "4286f4",
        "is_default": true,
        "customer": {
            "customer_name": "Testcustomer",
            "customer_uuid": "179fe73d-ec67-45ac-8dac-e2456ccd9b48"
        }
    }
]
```

Using the `customer_uuid` in the URL shows the device groups related to that customer

`/api/v1/device-groups/179fe73d-ec67-45ac-8dac-e2456ccd9b48` returns data of the device groups attached to the specified `customer_uuid`

The problem I am facing is that whenever there are multiple device groups related to a `customer_uuid` it results in a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. I want to list all the device groups that are related to the specified `customer_uuid`.

My `serializers.py`:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'customer_uuid')

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='customer_uuid')

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('device_group_name', 'group_uuid', 'color', 'is_default', 'customer')
```

My `views.py`:

```
class DeviceGroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer
    lookup_field = 'customer_uuid'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = DeviceGroup.objects.all()
        customer_uuid = self.request.query_params.get('customer_uuid', None)
        if customer_uuid is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(customer_uuid=customer_uuid)
        return queryset
```

What do I need to change so all device groups related to a `customer_uuid` are returned?

Comment: why you set `many=False` if you want all? `CustomerSerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='customer_uuid')`

Comment: If I set `many=True`, `/api/v1/device-groups` gives a `TypeError: Customer object is not iterable` and `/api/v1/device-groups/<customer_uuid>/` still gives the `MultipleObjectsReturned` error.

Comment: `MultipleObjectsReturned` could mean that you use `queryset.get` where you should use `queryset.filter`. I guess this code snippet is missing.